# Merging records based on condition in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have multiple rows for members and want to merge them based on the values of two columns by giving priority to the value 'Yes'.

```
Name | Status1  |  Status2
Jon  |  Yes     |  No
Jon  |  No      |  Yes
```

I want the query to return

```
Name | Status1 | Status2
Jon  |  Yes    |  Yes
```

So, if the column has `Yes` even once, it has to assign `Yes` for the person and `No` otherwise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT Name, MAX(Status1) AS Status1, MAX(Status2) AS Status2
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY Name
```

You can test, play with it using sample data

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'Jon' Name, 'Yes' Status1, 'No' Status2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Jon', 'No', 'Yes' 
)
SELECT Name, MAX(Status1) AS Status1, MAX(Status2) AS Status2
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY Name
```

with result

```
Row Name    Status1 Status2  
1   Jon     Yes     Yes
```

Comment: Oh so max does the job even for strings? Let me try it. As always very thankful to your quick help.

Comment: Worked! Thank you.

Comment: @MartinWeitzmann - if there is at least one value of Yes - it selects Yes, otherwise  - No

Comment: I mean the mechanics behind it - why is it choosing Yes over No

Comment: @MartinWeitzmann - functions like MAX, MIN, etc. use the lexicographic order when applied to strings. So, 'Y' is considered greater than 'N' thus gets as a result for MAX. hope this answers your question, unless you mean something else - let me know

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Mikhail's answer, I am adding another solution with MsSQL. Syntax may be different but the logic would be similar:

```
create table test
(id int , name1 varchar(10), name2 varchar(10))

insert into test values (1,'yes','no')
insert into test  values (2,'no','no')
insert into test values (3,'yes','yes')

declare @searchKey varchar(10) = 'yes'
declare @cols varchar(255) = (SELECT STUFF((
    SELECT ', ' + c.name 
    FROM sys.columns  c
    JOIN sys.types AS t ON c.user_type_id=t.user_type_id
    WHERE t.name != 'int'  AND t.name != 'bit' AND t.name !='date' AND t.name !='datetime'
        AND object_id =(SELECT object_id FROM sys.tables WHERE name='test')
    FOR XML PATH('')),1,2,''))

declare @sql nvarchar(max) = 'SELECT * from test where '''+@searchKey+''' in ('+@cols+')'
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Edit: Please note that this solution checks all the columns of a table if a specific value is included by any column. Assume the OP needs to check 100 columns, until `status100`, then I believe a dynamic solution like that would be more handy.

Comment: I don't get the point of this answer.  Mikhail's solution works just fine in SQL Server -- and any other database.

Comment: Mikhail's answer states the two column static, status1 and status2. Assume he needs to check 100 columns, we need to state until max(state100) there. Here, all dynamic. @GordonLinoff